# Use of tags based on errors that are part of the question

Tags: discussion, tags

The following question:

[Is this a pun? "Der wird sie einmal heiraten -- so sogt er"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/is-this-a-pun-der-wird-sie-einmal-heiraten-so-sogt-er)

asked if something is a pun which happens not to be a pun.

Is it useful to leave the pun-tag on?

Is it useful to put a tag X if one asks if something is X which might not be?

Answer (score 5):

I think that it makes sense to tag questions of type "Is this *X* or not?" with `X`. The question already implies that the word/phrase/etc in question might not be *X*. Thus, the attentive reader normally won't be mislead by the tag.

In situations however, where the original poster asks about *Y* but tags the question `X` because [s]he assumes it is about *X* we should change the tag from `X` to `Y`. In my opinion, it's more important that German learners are not mislead by wrong tags than the fact that people might find the mistagged question easier as they might have the same misunderstanding as the original poster. Thus, I think a question shouldn't be tagged *X* if it doesn't deal with *X* - even if the poster thought it did. This, of course, excludes the case above, asked here by thei.

Comment: The question asks "is this a pun?" and all answers reply that it is not. Perhaps you could come up with another situation? No-one would be misled by this example. I think we should base our policy on how the tags are used, i.e. whether it would be useful to find "false puns" when looking through pun-tagged questions.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't get your question right. We're talking about questions of type "Is this X or not?", right? I can't think of any situation where it would be bad to tag this question *X*. I will edit my answer...

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood you. Much clearer now :)